# Signals and Slots Constructor Failing Due to Non-Static Member Function Call

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm just trying out the signal/slots method for the first time. I don't really understand the error I'm getting so I'm hoping someone can enlighten me a little.

### The Error

This is the error I get:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
                this, Instrument::onConnected);
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
                                             ()
```

### My Method:

Here is a shortened version of my header file:

```
class Instrument : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Instrument(QObject *parent, InstrumentSocket& socket);
    virtual ~Instrument();

signals:
    void NotifyConnected();
    void NotifyDisconnected();

public slots:
    void onConnected();
    void onDisconnected();

private:
    InstrumentSocket& m_instSocket;
    void WireConnections();
```

Here is where I try to wire the signals and slots together which is called upon in the constructor of my .cpp file. `m_instSocket` is already initialised in the constructor too:

```
void Instrument::WireConnections()
{
    connect(&m_instSocket, &InstrumentSocket::NotifyConnected,
            this, Instrument::onConnected); //This is where the error is highlighted
    connect(&m_instSocket, &InstrumentSocket::NotifyDisconnected,
            this, Instrument::onDisconnected);
}
```

I then have corresponding methods of the above functions too but I'm trying to keep it short so I'm including this as an example:

```
void Instrument::onConnected()
{
    emit NotifyConnected(); //don't worry about this
}
```

Comment: I think you have to prepend address operator to `Instrument::onConnected`, i.e. write it as `&Instrument::onConnected` instead.

Comment: You put a `&` in front of the signal, but not in front of the slot ? Does that not ring a bell ? ^^

Comment: Slyps has the answer; also: are you using Qt 5? and just in case, can you add InstrumentSocket::NotifyConnected and InstrumentSocket::NotifyDisconnected signatures?

Comment: vahancho and slyps got it right >_<